# Error installing numpy+mkl on window 7 64bit

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.6, windows64

I am trying to install numpy+mkl .whl file using pip for installing scipy+mkl .whl file but getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>pip install numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.zip
    Processing c:\program files\python36\scripts\numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.zip
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "c:\program files\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
            buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\MD0AA4~1.MAH\\AppData\\Local\\T
    emp\\pip-pveig4yh-build\\setup.py'
```

---

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\MD0AA4~1.MAH\AppData\Local\Temp \pip-pveig4yh-build\

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You say you tried installing the `.whl` file but the command says you tried to install a `.zip` file. Have you tried the `.whl` files from [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or just `pip install numpy`?

Comment: @michael  yeah I tried .whl but it's showing error that "not finding the .whl file"  . First I downloaded the numpy+mkl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/   then try to install it from that folder but it's not worked at all . Yeah using pip install numpy works for numpy but scipy can't install using pip install scipy . That's create more errors .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by renaming .zip extension to .whl before installing.

Apparently, my download manager downloaded the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ as zip file like yours. The `FileNotFoundError` is because pip needs setup.py to install from zip but not from wheel.